# css border-bottom out of control

Tags: html, css

```
echo '<p class="post"><h3>'.$result['title'].'</h3><object class="video" width="95%" height="55%">
        <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/'.$match[0].'?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US&rel=0">
        </param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
        <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/'.$match[0].'?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US&rel=0"
        type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="opaque" allowscriptaccess="always"
        allowfullscreen="true" width="95%" height="55%"></embed></object><p class="desc">'.$result['description'].'</p></p>';
```

why does .post {border-bottom:2px black solid;} displays border at the top of the paragraph?

you don't believe me, try it for urself [HERE](http://lookaroundyou.net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't, you're just doing it wrong. There's no text in the `<p>` node for it to be under, and you've got a bottom margin defined. See the screenshot I'm about to upload.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpXLG.png]

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be nesting p tags.  Be sure your markup is correct.

Nested p tags will render as separate p tags.

Since you have nested p tags, your markup looks like this when rendered to the browser:

```
<p class="post"></p>
<h3>hobotnica zajebant</h3>
<object>...</object>
<p class="desc">...</p>
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what these fellas said.  If you don't have content or a height defined of an element, it will appear just like, so it's doing what it's supposed to.

You can add a `padding/margin/height` to your `<p>` if you want that to appear different.  Or put it on the element containing your movie, rather than the empty